# assign appliance.local to appliance.mydomain.com

Tags: internal-dns, freeipa

I have an appliance that uses mdns to handle accessing of iot devices and plugins.  when you click on add a plugin it goes to appliance.local to add that plugin to the system. As far as I can tell it is hard coded that way.  I have seen a few other devices that do something similer.  Im using freeipa with bind9 to handle dns and identity.

Does any one know if its possible to alias appliance.local to appliance.domain.com.